# Atrix Lapdock Mounting Solution

Tags: hardware, laptop

I was wondering if I could mount a Raspberry Pi on the back of the Atrix Lapdock if I would be using it connected to the Pi as a laptop. I asked a simmilar question [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27076/integrated-pi-laptop-with-the-atrix-lapdock) and was told the Sugru might work for this. Could someone give me directions on how to do this?

Comment: Have you considered zip ties or velcro, both are cheaper than sugru, and may provide a more secure mounting, especially if you get a case for your pi as added protection. You could just mount it to the back of the screen.

Comment: That seems like it would work, how would I do the cables (I'm going to use a Pi 2 the 1GB ram one)?

Comment: you could just tie them up neatly with velcro cable ties.

Comment: What I ment was what cables would I use? This may be a bit off topic, but whatever.

Comment: http://www.instructables.com/id/The-Raspberry-Pi-Lapdock-Connection/step1/Parts-Required/

Answer (score 1):

Video on parts you need and how to build it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rcOVVnBAJLE

Parts and Diagrams of different ways to connect your pi (based on the model): https://daveden.wordpress.com/2012/09/20/how-to-connect-your-motorola-lapdock-to-your-rapsberry-pi/

Also a huge Thread of Raspberry Pi Users who have already built them and all the info they learned along the way : https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=6747&p=85599&hilit=atrix+4g+lapdock#p85599

Some of the best ones done that I have seen: http://www.kappasite.pwp.blueyonder.co.uk/raspberry_pip3.htm

http://www.kappasite.pwp.blueyonder.co.uk/raspberry_pip.htm

http://www.kappasite.pwp.blueyonder.co.uk/raspberry_pip.htm